# Data cleaning for dutch text - Sentiment analysis

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, text-processing

I am looking for few best practices to clean up the Dutch text.
What I have done so far:
1. Used regex to remove all special characters, digits etc.
2. Spacy _ NL model for lemmetization of the words
3. NLTK stopwords for dutch
4. collecting adjectives for sentiment.

Feature vector - Count Vector

But the text is not getting cleaned as expected. There is no clean line for positive and negative.

I am looking for some guidance or solution to solve NLP problems in Dutch.

Comment: Please give some examples from the raw data, how you cleaned, and what your expected output should look like.

Comment: Ex: "Ben zeer tevreden over de nieuwe packet geen haperingen YouTube werkt perfect ben zeer tevreden het installeren ging super snel"

Comment: Expected - "tevreden nieuwe packet haperingen perfect tevreden installeren super snel" .. combination of noun and adj. I am using lemmitaziation from spacy and pos tags from alpino